# Load script from PowerShell ISE's command environment

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

Is there a way to open a script file ($profile or otherwise) from within the IDE's command environment (`PS>` prompt), such that it loads in the IDE itself?

```
# loads the current user/current host profile in Notepad (probably because .PS1 is associated w/ Notepad.exe)
PS > ii $profile

# same for any random script file
PS > ii .\Foo.ps1
```

Comment: I changed the "open with" property of my .ps1 files to powershell ise. Then  "ii $profile" will open my profile in ise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Invoke-Item`, just use `ise`.  When run from the ISE, it will load the file.

```
PS> ise myscript.ps1
```

To make Invoke-Item behave like you want (as well as double-clicking from Explorer), you can associate .ps1 files with `powershell_ise.exe`.  Here is a blog post [explaining how to do this](http://tomtalks.uk/2013/01/associate-ps1-powershell-files-to-open-in-powershell-ise/) if you need it.

Comment: In the interim (awaiting an answer), I decided to make an alias to the IDE using that very alias, only discover that it already existed.

Comment: The `ise` command seems to choose a ISE at random if multiple ISEs are open.  You would think that it would select the ISE from which the command is executed.